# pthread_detach behavior when there is an existing a joiner

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I am relatively new to POSIX thread implementations and I have a corner case behavior that I am not sure about.

As per my understanding one can call pthread_deatch() on a join-able pthread to mark it detached.

After a thread is detached it doesnt need to wait for someone to join in order to have it's resources released by the system.

My question is what if a join-able thread (let's call it thread B) was joined by a thread (lets call it a thread A) after thread B was created. Lets also assume that thread B was under execution when thread A joined, thus causing thread A to be suspended till thread B finished its execution. Meanwhile thread C called pthread_deatch() on thread B.

In such a scenario what should happen to thread A which is in suspended state waiting for thread B to finish. Will thread B continue execution and then thread A is awoken to fetch the return value of B? Or does thread A is awoken as soon as thread B is marked detached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POSIX description for `pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html#) says:

> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the `thread`
>   argument to `pthread_join()` does not refer to a joinable thread.

If you call `pthread_deatch()` on the thread being joined in another thread, then the thread is no longer joinable, so behaviour of `pthread_join()` becomes undefined.

In other words, this isn't allowed.

If you find you need to wake up the joining thread "early" then you could either use thread cancellation on it (`pthread_join()` is a cancellation point) or set up a condition variable for it to wait on rather than `pthread_join()`.